# How to separate several HttpClient instances metrics in reactor-netty

Tags: spring-boot, reactor-netty

I have multiple `HttpClient` instances with different pools, and I would like to see how much direct memory they consume. I have enabled metrics as stated in [reference guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_6), and I do indeed have exposed metric `reactor.netty.bytebuf.allocator.used.direct.memory`, but only one value for all clients. Is the allocation shared across multiple instances, or do they overwrite each others values? Is there an option to separate them with additional tag?

Comment: It is shared - by default io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator#DEFAULT is used